# Потеря фокуса элемента Input

Tags: jquery, javascript

Нужно вызвать функцию, после того, как пользователь введет текст в текстовое поле и отведет мышку от поля или же перейдет к следующему

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно событие blur - потеря фокуса элементом, или onmouseout - "отведет мышку от поля"